# Django Object gets created twice

Tags: python, django

So I have a big app and was able to find out where the "error" is located (That's why I don't need to upload more of my code)

```py
image_model = Image_model(
    user = user,
    lan = lan,
    lon = lon,
    width = width,
    height = height,
    image_name = image_name,
    image_name_preview = image_name_preview,
    image = original_image,
    preview_image = preview_image,
    whatisseen = whatisseen,
    timestamp_create = timestamp_create
)

image_model.save()

RoomChatMessage.objects.create(
    room = room,
    user = user,
    content = message,
    image = image_modal,
)
payload = {"Success": "Message successfully added"}
```

So when I call the function around the two objects the image object is created and after that the RoomChatMessage object. But now I have a problem:

When I commend the image_modal out (the full object) and only create the RoomChatMessage (without the image) it works fine. But if I call the function like this I get one Image Object and two Message Objects - but why?

Comment: Do you have constructed signals for the `Image_model`?

Comment: No I don't but I do have a signal for roomchatmessage

Comment: can you share the signal for the `RoomChatMessage`? Often using signals tend to be quite error-prone.

Comment: see an article I wrote a few months ago: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/signals.html

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem great article

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem would you like to post that as an answer? I could accept it